# Why is the Quicktime plugin trying to play an embedded Flash video, and how can I correct it?

Tags: internet-explorer, flash, quicktime

I'm trying to view [this page](http://redlettermedia.com/plinkett/star-wars/star-wars-episode-iii-revenge-of-the-sith/) in IE9. It has flash videos embedded but for some reason the Quicktime Plugin, not the Flash plugin, is being used to play them (which obviously doesn't work, and Quicktime throws an error). How can I tell IE9 to use the proper plugin? I have Flash installed and updated to the latest version. Rudimentary troubleshooting such as using compatability view does nothing.

Here's the embed code the site is using:

```
<embed src="http://blip.tv/play/huARgpiyHwA%2Em4v" 
       type="application/x-shockwave-flash" height="360" width="580" 
       allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true"></embed>
```

A few additional items of information:

- I'm using Windows 7 and opening the MIME/File Type Settings for Quicktime just brings up the Windows Control Panel for filetype associations. There is no option for Flash content or .swf that I can see.
- Reinstalling Flash doesn't fix the problem.
- Disabling the Quicktime plugin from the IE addons window doesn't correct the behavior, instead IE simply doesn't load any plugin at all.
- Uninstalling Quicktime DOES work. With no Quicktime on my system IE will use Flash just fine. Unfortuantely however, I need to keep Quicktime around.
- The [page I linked](http://redlettermedia.com/plinkett/star-wars/star-wars-episode-iii-revenge-of-the-sith/) is the only page I've seen that has this problem. Every other Flash video I've seen on the internet has played properly.
- This might be an IE-specific bug, since Firefox plays the media properly with the Flash plugin.

Answer (score 2):

This site has various tutorial videos that have the same problem. I haven't found a solution to this either other than uninstalling Quicktime. Not sure what the heck is going on here.

[CGTuts - IE9 Flash or Quicktime player confusion](http://cg.tutsplus.com/tutorials/autodesk-3d-studio-max/3ds-max-2010-the-graphite-modeling-tools-day-1/)

Plays just fine in Chrome and Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

It plays in Flash for me on Google Chrome. It sounds like flash video is associated with Quicktime on your computer.

Alter your Quicktime settings:

1. Start the **Quicktime Player**.
2. Go to **Edit > Preferences > QuickTime Preferences**
3. Select the “**Browser**” tab and hit the **MIME Settings** button.
4. Under the **Video** column, make sure that both **QuickTime Movie** checkboxes are ticked.
5. Now go to **miscellaneous** and uncheck the **Flash Media** option.
6. Click on OK button.
   Now
7. go to the **File Types** tab
8. Perform step **4** and **5**
9. Also, under the **streaming** tab, select **automatic** and check **instant on**.

(from: http://forums.techarena.in/windows-software/1403202.htm#post5259013)

Also, you might try re-installing flash. Likely, this will re-associate flash content with Adobe Flash again.

Clean Uninstall: http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/141/tn_14157.html

Install: http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/

Comment: Neither of these options worked for me. Clicking MIME Settings and File Types in Quicktime both open the Windows Control Panel for file associations (I'm on Win7), and there's no option for Flash Media, not even .swf. I tried reinstalling Flash, and no luck. Uninstalling Quicktime did the trick, but unfortunately I'm forced to reinstall it if I want to use iTunes again. Note that the page that I linked is the only place where I've seen this bug happen, every other page plays Flash fine.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue and what helped where the video was playing in Quicktime even though the default set for .mp4 files was Windows Media Player.

It would either load very slowly before playing or not at all, and I did the following to fix it.

1. Start the Quicktime Player.
2. Go to `Edit` -> `Preferences` -> `QuickTime Preferences`.
3. Select the `Browser` tab.
4. Uncheck `Play movies automatically`. Click `Apply` and then `Ok`.

Went back to my problem video and this time it played fine and using desired player.